# How to make property decorator to be called when in-place modifying an attribute?

Tags: python, dictionary, properties, decorator, python-decorators

I would like to know how to make @property decorator to call constructor when modifying an object rather than assigning it.

```
class Celsius:
    def __init__(self, temperature = [0]):
        self._temperature = temperature
    @property
    def temperature(self):
        print("Getting value")
        return self._temperature
    @temperature.setter
    def temperature(self, value):
        print('setting temperature')
        self._temperature = value
a=Celsius()
a.temperature
Getting value
Out[10]: [0]
a.temperature = 7
setting temperature
a.temperature = [7,8]
setting temperature
a.temperature[0] = 0
Getting value
a.temperature
Getting value
Out[14]: [0, 8]
```

As you can see, if assigning temperature, property is called meanwhile if the list is modified it does not call the constructor but calls the "displayer"

I know that this is probably not done with  @property but it's the closest idea I've found.

In fact, how does it changes value of temperature and _temperature in-place?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are seeing the "Getting value" output when setting a value is because you are modifying the _temperature variable.

To modify a variable it must be retrieved first. When you overwrite a variable, it does not need to be retrieved first and can just be set.

The reason you don't see a "setting temperature" output, is because you are actually modifying _temperature's underlying object, a list, so your property setter is not used.

Answer (score 0):

The sequence:

```
>>> a=Celsius()
>>> a.temperature = [7,8]
setting temperature
>>> a.temperature[0] = 0
getting value
```

Is particularly interesting because you gave access to the `_temperature` list and an evil user could break you `Celsius` instance. One would like something like this:

```
>>> a=Celsius()
>>> a.temperature = [7,8]
setting temperature (I CHECK THAT THOSE VALUES ARE CONSISTENT)
>>> a.temperature[0] = 0
setting ONE temperature (I CHECK THAT THIS VALUE IS CONSISTENT)
```

Basically, you lost control over your object because you can't check what an evil user can do. This seems a dangerous design. Here's a suggestion: *never share a mutable object with the external world, always provide an immutable object or a copy.* (This ensures compliance with the [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter)). Replace:

```
@property
def temperature(self):
    print("getting value")
    return self._temperature
```

By:

```
@property
def temperature(self):
    print("getting value")
    return list(self._temperature)
```

And try your test case:

```
>>> a=Celsius()
>>> a.temperature = [7,8]
setting temperature (I CHECK THAT THOSE VALUES ARE CONSISTENT)
>>> a.temperature[0] = 0
getting value
>>> a.temperature
getting value
[7, 8] # NO MODIFICATION HERE
```

Now your `Celsius` object is protected against wild modifications: if you want to change the `_temperature` list, you have to provide a full list that should be checked by the setter.

If you want to change a single value, this is still possible, but there is call to the setter (and a possible check):

```
>>> a=Celsius()
>>> a.temperature = [7,8]
setting temperature (I CHECK THAT THOSE VALUES ARE CONSISTENT)
>>> new_temp = [0] + a.temperature[1:]
getting value
>>> a.temperature = new_temp
setting temperature (I CHECK THAT THOSE VALUES ARE CONSISTENT)
>>> a.temperature
getting value
[0, 8]
```

If you absolutely want the user to set an item by index, you have to write a function manually:

```
class Celsius:
    ...

    def set_temperature_item(self, i, v):
        print ("setting ONE temperature (I CHECK THAT THIS VALUE IS CONSISTENT)")
        self._temperature[i] = v

>>> a=Celsius()
>>> a.temperature = [7,8]
setting temperature (I CHECK THAT THOSE VALUES ARE CONSISTENT)
>>> a.set_temperature_item(0, 0)
setting ONE temperature (I CHECK THAT THIS VALUE IS CONSISTENT)
>>> a.temperature
getting value
[0, 8]
```

## Property

I think you can't do this with a `property` because when you write:

```
a.temperature[0] = 0
```

It's equivalent to:

```
a.__getattribute__("temperature").__setitem__(0, 0)
```

And you can't decide on the `__getattribute__` call what will happen next: just get the value or use it to set an item.